# Worksheet_Protection event, similar to Worksheet_Change?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking around for a `Worksheet_Protection` event for Excel.  The idea being that when a user protects (or unprotects) a worksheet/workbook, I would like some macros to fire.

Is there an event similar to `Worksheet_Change` or `Sheet_Change`?  If not, any ideas on a workaround?

I was thinking I could use the `Workbook_Change` event to check if the workbook is protected each time a change occurs, but am thinking that might slow my workbook down, no?

(I know I could make a macro that locks the workbook, which is pretty straightforward. I was wondering though if there's a way to detect if the user used Excel's built in "Protect Workbook" button)

Comment: Find the ID of the button then do something with `Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).Controls`? Edit: er that's for VBE controls ooops XD but you get the idea ^_^; Edit2: excel 2000 [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213552)

Comment: @findwindow Excel 2000, really? How useful is that advice for a ribbon command?